# Does "!!!" have a special meaning in a Lightroom keywords file?

Tags: lightroom, software, keywords

We have some Lightroom keyword files which have keywords which begin with three exclamation marks ("!!!") - something like this:

```
!!!colour list -  IMPORT HERE 

!!!location list  -  IMPORT HERE

!!!plant list -  IMPORT HERE
```

The exclamation marks have any special meaning for the import engine (comments?) or it is just a way in which a user marked some placeholders?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I couldn't find any documentation of any special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked with my Lightroom 4, and found nothing special about an exclamation point, singly or in triplicate. I also notice that you're spelling 'colour' with a "U", while Adobe, true to their American roots, uses the non-U spelling in their help files.

I'm in Canada, and downloaded my copy from adobe-dot-com; I don't know if I'm using an American edition or if they may have localized English for other regions. But if searching your copy's help file also doesn't return results for the spelling "colour" then I would be confident that these are keywords imported from elsewhere.